# Rails: Form help -- supplying method with argument

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, model-view-controller, arguments, models

I am relatively new to rails and have attempted to write a small Loan app where a User can make a Loan to someone and this app can track balances / etc.  I am adding a function to the Loan model that handles payments and have gotten this far (draw attention to the `make_payment(value)` portion:

### loan.rb

```
class Loan < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :lender, :class_name => 'User'
  belongs_to :borrower, :class_name => 'User'
  has_many :payments

  default_scope -> { order(created_at: :desc) }

  validates :amount, presence: true
  validates :lender, presence: true
  validates :borrower, presence: true

  def make_payment(value)
    remainder = amount - value
    update_attribute(:amount, remainder)
    return remainder
  end
end
```

I can use this to correctly deduct a value from the original Loan amount, but I cannot seem to make it work using views and a form.  Currently my view is as follows:

### app/views/loans/show.html.erb

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <ul>
      <li><strong>Lender</strong>: <%= @loan.lender.username %></li>
      <li><strong>Borrower</strong>: <%= @loan.borrower.username %></li>
      <li><strong>Amount Remaining</strong>: <%= @loan.amount %></li>
    </ul>
    <section>
      <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <%= form_for @loan do |f| %>

          <%= f.label :make_payment %>  <!--confusion -->
          <%= f.number_field :value, class: 'form-control' %>  <!--confusion -->

          <%= f.submit "Submit Payment", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_loan_path(@loan) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', loans_path %>
```

When I try to reach the page, I get an error `wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)` which makes complete sense, but I'd like the value submitted in the form to be the argument (value) for the function `make_payment(value)`.  Should I use `form_for @loan.make_payment do |f|` or something else entirely?  I'm sure this is a simple fix, I just can't seem to find the answer I'm looking for.

Comment: on which line is it throwing error? paste the complete error log

Comment: the form you have added. that form should be for payment object.In loan controller show action, you should initialize payment object. so the submitting form will take you to payment controller create action where you will create payment with the amount which he entered.That payment belongs to loan. the number_field should have payment attribute then you should have after_create callback in payment model where you should update loan's amount which is same thing which are you currently doing in make payment method in loan. it will update loan amount with the pending

Comment: its throwing the error on line 12 `def make_payment(value)`

Answer (score 0):

A nice RESTful solution could look like this:

```
resources :loans, shallow: :true do
  resources :payments, only: :create
end
```

---

```
class PaymentsController < ApplicationController

  # POST /loans/:loan_id/payments
  def create
    @loan = Loan.find(params[:loan_id])
    @loan.make_payment(payment)
    if @load.save
      redirect_to @loan, notice: "Payment successful"
    else
      redirect_to @loan, alert: "Payment count not be processed"
    end 
  end

  private 

  def payment
    require(:loan).require(:payment)[:payment]
  end
end
```

And then your form would look like this:

```
<%= form_for @loan, url: loan_payments_path(loan: @loan), method: :post do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :payment %>
  <%= f.number_field :payment, class: 'form-control' %>
  <%= f.submit "Submit Payment", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: In a previous post I was told it was unnecessary to make a seperate controller and that all I needed was a method in the Loan model.  Is this not the case?

Comment: unnecessary is the wrong word - there are many ways to solve this task. This is one that takes a restful approach and treats payments as actual resource. Its quite possible to kludge something into your `LoansController#update` method but that's not how I would solve it.  Simple is often actually more about  having parts that only do one job rather than having a few parts that do everything.

Comment: great!  I figure I should learn to do it the right way anyway.  It can't seem to find the route for payments even though it shows up in `rake routes` as `/loans/:loan_id/payments(.:format)`

Comment: also, in your response you wrote 
`routes :loans, shallow: :true do
  routes :payments, only: :create
end` 
Did you mean to write `resources` instead of `routes`

Comment: Yes it should be `resources` in both places @Jeremy.  The Rails guide can be found [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).

Comment: My apologies, but something is still wrong because when I attempt to view the page I am using a GET request while the page is stored as a POST request.

Comment: OOps my bad. Yes it should be `resources` and not routes - also the form should have `method: :post`. Edited.